# CloudFormation lowercase transformation function

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

The task is to convert the incoming parameter into lowercase letters like "Name-keyword", but the template does not pass validation:

Source code:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  NamePrefix:
    Type: String
    Description: Enter the name to create related resources.
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,30}$"
    ConstraintDescription: "Invalid name. It should be 3-30 characters long and can only contain letters, numbers, underscore, and hyphen."  

Recources:
  ECRRepository:
    Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: !Sub "${NamePrefix}-keyword"
```

My variant to make low case for "${NamePrefix}-keyword" according this example:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/StringFunctions/string_example.yaml

```
  ECRRepository:
    Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName:
        'Fn::Transform':
          Name: 'String'
          Parameters:
            InputString: !Sub "${NamePrefix}-keyword"
            Operation: Lower
```

Where is a problem?

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12cQG.png)

I got an error:

Incorrect type. Expected "string"

Comment: Just deploy the template, and ignore validation.